# count third dimension array segments

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [01] => Array
        (
            [03] => Array
                (
                [0] => 38
                [1] => 30
                )

        )
)
```

How do I count the segments in the third dimension?
So $arrayname[01][03] has 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `count` to count the number of elements in an array

```
count($arrayname["01"]["03"]);
```

Also keep in mind that your array keys are actually strings (not numbers)

Comment: Yep. It's *that* simple.